How to check for stale connections in a spring boot application
I have a spring boot application wherein I am calling a third-party POST API using RestTemplate. It mostly works and a JSON playload gets delivered successfully. However, randomly I am getting javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset exception
I have ruled out almost all the possible causes. However, as one of the causes is stale connections in the application, I am figuring out how to check that. Is there a way I can figure out/check if indeed there are stale connections in my application.
My Rest template declaration is
 @Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return
            restTemplateBuilder
                    .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(Integer.parseInt("60")))
                    .build();
}

This is how I am calling POST API
@Autowired
private RestTemplate requestTemplate;

try {
            response = requestTemplate.exchange(
                    "url",
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    request,
                    String.class
            );

            return response;
        }        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

I did a POC by creating a server and client application. However, I could not replicate the exception. Also tried finding out the ways of finding the staled connections. However, could not get useful results.
